# inequality for supremum

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Consider two bounded sequences $\{|A_i|\}_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ and $\{|B_i|\}_{i = 1}^{\infty}$, for some $\epsilon > 0$, suppose $\sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}||A_i| - |B_i|| < \epsilon$ where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers, do we have
$|\sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}|A_i| - \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}|B_i|| < \epsilon$?

I can prove the above claim when using max not sup, but I have no idea how to prove rigorously when using sup. Here are my thoughts for the case max. Let $\alpha: = \max_{i \in S}|A_i| = |A_{i_j}|$ and $\beta := \max_{i \in S}|B_i| = |B_{i_k}|$ where $S$ is a finite set, and suppose now we have $|\alpha - \beta| \geq \epsilon$, i.e., $||A_{i_j}| - |B_{i_k}|| \geq \epsilon$, and without loss of generality assume $|A_{i_j}| \geq |B_{i_k}|$, then we have $|A_{i_j}| - |B_{i_j}| \geq |A_{i_j}| - |B_{i_k}| \geq \epsilon$, contradicting the fact that $\max_{i \in S}||A_i| - |B_i|| < \epsilon$.

Comment: What are $A_i$'s and $B_i$'s?

Comment: Just a sequence of numbers. @tattwamasi amrutam

Comment: What you need here is, essentially, the reverse triangle inequality for the [$\infty$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-infinity#Sequence_space). Even if you're not familiar, you can still follow the usual steps. First, show the triangle inequality, $\|a_n + b_n\|_\infty \le \|a_n\|_\infty + \|b_n\|_\infty$, where $\|x_n\|_\infty := \sup_i |x_i|$. Then, use this triangle inequality to prove the reverse triangle inequality, $|\|a_n\|_\infty - \|b_n\|_\infty| \le \|a_n - b_n\|_\infty$. Finally, substitute $a_n = |A_n|$ and $b_n = |B_n|$.

Comment: You need hypothesis on $A$ and $B$. It could be that $\sup_i ||A_i|-|B_i|| < \varepsilon$ but $sup_i |A_i|=sup_i |B_i|=\infty$ and so their difference would not be well-defined. Take for instance $A_i=i+1$ and $B_i=i$.

Comment: The sequences of $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are both bounded sequences. @SilvioM

Comment: @Marshall it would be better for the question to be self-explanatory, please add this information on the text

Answer (score 0):

The $\max$ here is not necessarily well-defined.

Let $x(i) = |A_i|$ and $y(i) = |B_i|$, then we have two sequences of real numbers. Since the two sequences are non decreasing and bounded then $\sup_{i \in \mathbb N} (x(i)) < \infty$ and $\sup_{i \in \mathbb N} (y(i)) < \infty$.

Let $z:=\sup_{i \in \mathbb N}(z(i))$. Then from triangle inequality we have $|x +y  | \leq |x| +|y|.$

Since $|x| \leq  |x-y|+ (|-y|=|y|) \Rightarrow |x|-|y| \leq |x-y|$.

Also,

Since $|y| \leq  |y-x|+ (|-x|=|x|) \Rightarrow |y|-|x| \leq |x-y|$.

Then we get $$||x|-|y|| \leq |x-y|.$$

Thus, the given information is equivalent means exactly expected.